# get path of 2 images in codeigniter 3

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am able to get path of one image but how to get the path of the second image here is my code:

View:

```
 echo "<div class='form-group'>";
 echo form_label('Brand Logo');
 $img=array('name'=>'brand_logo','class'=>'form-control');
 echo form_upload($img);
 echo "</div>";

 echo "<div class='form-group'>";
 echo form_label('Brand Banner');
 $banner=array('name'=>'banner','class'=>'form-control');
 echo form_upload($banner);
 echo "</div>";
```

Controller:

```
function upload_brand()
{
    $rules=['upload_path'=>'./assets/brand_images','allowed_types'=>'gif|jpg|png|jpeg'];
    $this->load->library('upload',$rules);
    if($this->upload->do_upload('brand_logo') && $this->upload->do_upload('banner'))
    {
       $data=$this->upload->data();
       print_r($data);
    }
    else
    {
        $upload_error=$this->upload->display_errors();
        $this->load->view('admin/create_brand',compact('upload_error'));
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it 2 ways:

Duplicating logic:

```
function upload_brand() {
    $rules = ['upload_path' => './assets/brand_images', 'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg'];
    $this->load->library('upload', $rules);
    if ($this->upload->do_upload('brand_logo')) {
        $data1 = $this->upload->data();
        //print_r($data1);
    } else {
        $upload_error = $this->upload->display_errors();
        $this->load->view('admin/create_brand', compact('upload_error'));
        exit;
    }
    if ($this->upload->do_upload('banner')) {
        $data2 = $this->upload->data();
        print_r($data1);
        print_r($data2);
    } else {
        $upload_error = $this->upload->display_errors();
        $this->load->view('admin/create_brand', compact('upload_error'));
        exit;
    }
}
```

Foreach:

```
function upload_brand() {
    $rules = ['upload_path' => './assets/brand_images', 'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg'];
    $this->load->library('upload', $rules);
    $uploads = array('brand_logo', 'banner');
    $files = array();
    foreach ($uploads as $fieldname) {
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload($fieldname)) {
            $upload_error = $this->upload->display_errors();
            $this->load->view('admin/create_brand', compact('upload_error'));
            exit;
        }
        $files[] = $this->upload->data();
    }
    print_r($files);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to upload multiple files using codeigniter.
https://github.com/stvnthomas/CodeIgniter-Multi-Upload

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged and this would be better suited as a comment.